# Win32 popup window "shaking" on resize

Tags: c++, winapi, popup, window, resize

I'm writing a C++ program with a topmost window so you don't have any default way of resizing, or at least not to my knowledge. So I've implemented a resize, which is working fine except for 1 detail.

When I resize the window on the right or bottom it works perfectly, but when I'm resizing left or on the top, then the right, or bottom part, depending on which way you're resizing, shakes. I already "fixed" it partially so when you're downsizing it looks fine, but when you're upsizing the window it still shakes.

I also already tried to disable and enable the redraw when resizing but that screws things up completely,

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
GetCursorPos(&m_MousePos);
  int x( m_rWindowStart.left ),
     y( m_rWindowStart.top ),
     w( m_pWindow->GetWidth() ),
     h( m_pWindow->GetHeight() );
  //sizing
  switch (m_SizingDir)
  {
  case SIZING_DIR_LEFT:
     //x += m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;

     w = m_rWindowStart.right - m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x + x;
     w /= m_SnapSizing;
     w *= m_SnapSizing;

     x = m_rWindowStart.right - w;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_TOP:
     y += m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - y;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_RIGHT:
     w = m_rWindowStart.right - m_rWindowStart.left + m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_BOTTOM:
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - m_rWindowStart.top + m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_LEFTTOP:
     x += m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;
     w = m_rWindowStart.right - x;
     y += m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - y;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_LEFTBOTTOM:
     x += m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;
     w = m_rWindowStart.right - x;
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - m_rWindowStart.top + m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_RIGHTTOP:
     w = m_rWindowStart.right - m_rWindowStart.left + m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;
     y += m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - y;
     break;
  case SIZING_DIR_RIGHTBOTTOM:
     w = m_rWindowStart.right - m_rWindowStart.left + m_MousePos.x - m_MousePosOld.x;
     h = m_rWindowStart.bottom - m_rWindowStart.top + m_MousePos.y - m_MousePosOld.y;
     break;
  }

  //window size snaps
  w /= m_SnapSizing;
  w *= m_SnapSizing;
  h /= m_SnapSizing;
  h *= m_SnapSizing;

  //limit sizing
  if (h < 20)
     h = 20;
  if (w < 20)
     w = 20;

  //move window ( x, y, w, h, repaint)
  m_pWindow->SetPosAndSize(x, y, w, h, true);
```

And the methods which are called from the m_pWindow

```
void Window::SetPosAndSize(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint)
{
  ASSERT( w >= 0, _T("w(Width) must be greater than 0") );
  ASSERT( h >= 0, _T("h(Height) must be greater than 0") );

  m_Width = w;
  m_Height = h;

  if( m_hWnd )
  {
     RECT rPos;

     GetRect( rPos );   
     AdjustFromClient(w, h);

     MoveWindow(m_hWnd, x, y, w, h, repaint);
  }
}
void Window::GetRect( RECT& r ) const
{
   ::GetWindowRect( m_hWnd, &r );
}
void Window::AdjustFromClient(int& w, int& h) const
{
   RECT rSize2be = { 0, 0, w, h };
   AdjustWindowRect(&rSize2be, m_Style, false);

   w = rSize2be.right-rSize2be.left;
   h = rSize2be.bottom-rSize2be.top;
}
```

Comment: Because when you resize from bottom/right the buffer is not repainted, when you resize top/left it is repainted. Learn how to do double buffering in your GUI framework.

Comment: I didn't look too closely, usual problem is that the relative mouse position changes when you move the left or top side of the window.  Just don't do it this way, write a message handler for WM_NCHITTEST instead.

Comment: (please post a new question with your new problem. Stack Overflow works best with one question and then multiple answers--it's not a forum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hans is right... you're going about this the hard way.

Write a message handler for `WM_NCHITTEST` (in MFC, override `::OnNcHitTest`) that returns HT_BOTTOM, HT_LEFT, etc etc depending on where you want the "borders" of your window to be, and let Windows handle the whole thing.

Comment: i made it work like that by not using the `WS_SYSMENU` style but this doen't solve the problem when the user resizes with the window contents visable, here' a release build of it  http://www.megaupload.com/?d=JNAAVFWG